# Fail in OR to + noun/gerund/infinitive?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

**TIL**: the phrase **["fail in + noun/gerund"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fail+in+(something))** means:

- *to not be successful in an attempt to do something.*

and the phrase **["fail to + infinitive"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fail)** means:

- *leave something undone*

According to the meanings above; thus:

> 1. The king **fails in** `the throne`.
>
>    > This means ***the king does something unsuccessfully in his reign.***
> 2. The king **fails to** `the throne`.
> 3. The king **fails to** `claim` the throne.
> 4. The king **fails in** `claiming` the throne.
>
>    > These mean the same as ***the king claims the throne unsuccessfully.***

**Do they have any other differences?**

`Thank you`

Comment: Your examples #1 and #2 don't look like valid English to me in *any* context. And example #4 is "unusual" phrasing, to say the least - but most likely it would be interpreted as meaning *The king **made an error of judgement** by claiming the throne*.

Comment: To start with, `the throne` is not an action that one can attempt to do or fail to do, so neither of (1-2) work. _Claiming the throne_, on the other hand, **is** such an action, so (3) is grammatical, but it simply means he didn't claim the throne (for whatever reason), not that he claimed it unsuccessfully. And (4) doesn't work because _fail in_ is largely archaic now, used only in royal prescriptions and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your examples are not idiomatic.

In essence:

One fails **to** accomplish a task, assignment or similar

and

One fails **in** a project, ambition, aim, exam or similar

So the king would NOT fail **in the throne** but he might fail in his attempts to bring peace to his kingdom.

The king would NOT fail **to the throne** but he might fail to reclaim his throne after being deposed (as you suggest).

You might say that he failed **in claiming the throne** although it's a bit awkward. It's really his claim that fails.

It would read better if you wrote:

The king failed in his ambition to reclaim the throne. (He wouldn't be the king unless he had already been on the throne.)

By [Ronald Sole](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/41356/ronald-sole)